# ListView doesn't display data

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

I want to display a table with the items from an ObservableCollection of Type Vendor that exists.
The problem is that when I load the data in the collection it doesn't display it.
Here is my xaml code (i'm sure i'm missing something):

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid1">
    <ListView Name="ListViewVendors" 
              Margin="4,20,40,100" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=VendorsCollection}">
        <ListView.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </ListView.Background>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Vendor Name" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Contact Name" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ContactName}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Contact Phone" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ContactPhone}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Contact Fax" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ContactFax}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Contact Email" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ContactEmail}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Contact Website" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ContactWebSite}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: When and how are you loading the data in the collection (from View getting DataContext to ViewModel ctor to collection initialization to creating/adding items to collection)?

Comment: Look out for binding errors in the output window (as H.B. suggested) and make sure that the Property you are binding to calls the "OnPropertyChanged" in order to inform your view that the collection has changed. Your XAML looks good as far as I can see.

Comment: The problem was that the CollectionVariable didn't have the get; set;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be missing a [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) for the `ItemsSource` binding; either way might want to learn [how to debug bindings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx) so you can give us the binding errors you get.

Or perhaps you can even solve the problem yourself as those are usually very helpful.